# timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to convert the system datetime to timestamp in script task SSIS.

input date format: 29/05/2010 2:36 AM

output format: 29-15-2010 14:36:00

thanks
prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output doesn't quite match the input (the month becomes 15, and it goes from AM to PM).  I assume those are typos.  It should be something like:

```
string output = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy h:m tt", null).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

If it's user input, you may want `TryParseExact` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Givig the format of output into the string method gives the timestamp results.

string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss");

```
        DateTime dateformat = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(dateformat);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

thanks
prav

Answer (score 0):

```
       DateTime.Parse(input).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```